# C# ASP.NET MVC - Excel file can't open

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, epplus

I'm using EPPLUS with ASP.NET MVC and DataTable. When I create and download the Excel file, when I try to open it, I get this error:

> Your virus scanner can not open the file because it detected a problem with the file

But when I stop Windows Defender, it's working normally. Should I add some code in my controller, or something?

```cs
public ActionResult ExportToExcel(int ID)
{
    DESTEK_FORMUEntities db = new DESTEK_FORMUEntities();

    var formTablo = db.FORM_KAYIT.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ticket_id == ID && o.aktiflik == "1");

    var cozumTablo = db.COZUM_ADIMLARI.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ticket_id == ID);

    var siteMap = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/") + @"Reports\";

    string excelPath = siteMap + "destek.xlsx";
    
    string reportName = siteMap + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss") + ".xlsx";
    using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(excelPath)))
    {
        var kullaniciID = Session["KULLANICI_ID"];               

        ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets["Sayfa1"];        

        ws.Cells["B1"].Value = formTablo.bolge_no;
        ws.Cells["B2"].Value = formTablo.arayan_ad_soyad;
        ws.Cells["B3"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(kullaniciID);
        ws.Cells["B4"].Value = formTablo.gelis_adresi;

        ws.Cells["G1"].Value = formTablo.ticket_id;
        ws.Cells["G2"].Value = formTablo.ticket_gelis_saat.ToString().ToStringNull();
        ws.Cells["G3"].Value = formTablo.kapatilma_zamani.ToString().ToStringNull();

        if(formTablo.amaci_destek == true)
        {
            ws.Cells["B7"].Value = "✔";
        }

        if (formTablo.amaci_bilgi_almak == true)
        {
            ws.Cells["C7"].Value = "✔";
        }

        if (formTablo.amaci_bilgi_vermek == true)
        {
            ws.Cells["D7"].Value = "✔";
        }

        if (formTablo.amaci_istek == true)
        {
            ws.Cells["E7"].Value = "✔";
        }

        if (formTablo.amaci_hata == true)
        {
            ws.Cells["F7"].Value = "✔";
        }

        if (formTablo.amaci_oneri == true)
        {
            ws.Cells["G7"].Value = "✔";
        }

        if (formTablo.amaci_diger == true)
        {
            ws.Cells["H7"].Value = "✔";
        }

        ws.Cells["B10"].Value = formTablo.ticket_not;

        if (formTablo.cevap_yapilacak == true)
        {
            ws.Cells["B21"].Value = "✔";
        }

        if (formTablo.cevap_hemen == true)
        {
            ws.Cells["C21"].Value = "✔";
        }

        if (formTablo.cevap_arastirilacak == true)
        {
            ws.Cells["D21"].Value = "✔";
        }

        if (formTablo.cevap_islemde == true)
        {
            ws.Cells["E21"].Value = "✔";
        }

        if (formTablo.cevap_tamamlandi == true)
        {
            ws.Cells["F21"].Value = "✔";
        }

        if (formTablo.cevap_teknik == true)
        {
            ws.Cells["G21"].Value = "✔";
        }

        if (formTablo.cevap_diger == true)
        {
            ws.Cells["H21"].Value = "✔";
        }

        if (formTablo.yogunluk_bilgisi == "15 Dakika Sonra")
        {
            ws.Cells["B25"].Value = "✔";
        }

        if (formTablo.yogunluk_bilgisi == "30 Dakika Sonra")
        {
            ws.Cells["C25"].Value = "✔";
        }

        if (formTablo.yogunluk_bilgisi == "1 Saat Sonra")
        {
            ws.Cells["D25"].Value = "✔";
        }

        if (formTablo.yogunluk_bilgisi == "Gün İçerisinde")
        {
            ws.Cells["E25"].Value = "✔";
        }

        if (formTablo.yogunluk_bilgisi == "1 Gün Sonra")
        {
            ws.Cells["F25"].Value = "✔";
        }

        if (formTablo.durum == "Hemen Cevap")
        {
            ws.Cells["B29"].Value = "✔";
        }

        if (formTablo.durum == "Devam Ediyor")
        {
            ws.Cells["C29"].Value = "✔";
        }

        if (formTablo.durum == "Tamamlandı / Bilgilendirildi")
        {
            ws.Cells["D29"].Value = "✔";
        }

        ws.Cells["F29"].Value = formTablo.onem_durumu;

        if (cozumTablo.iletisime_gecildimi == "Evet")
        {
            ws.Cells["C32"].Value = "✔";
        }

        if (cozumTablo.iletisime_gecildimi == "Hayır")
        {
            ws.Cells["D32"].Value = "✔";
            ws.Cells["F31"].Value = cozumTablo.iletisim_olumsuz_nedeni;
        }

        ws.Cells["B34"].Value = cozumTablo.iletisime_gecilen;
        ws.Cells["B35"].Value = cozumTablo.iletisime_gecen;
        ws.Cells["B36"].Value = cozumTablo.iletisim_tarih.ToString().ToStringNull();
        ws.Cells["B37"].Value = cozumTablo.iletisim_adresi;

        if (cozumTablo.iletisim_bilgialmak == true)
        {
            ws.Cells["B40"].Value = "✔";
        }

        if (cozumTablo.iletisim_bilgivermek == true)
        {
            ws.Cells["C40"].Value = "✔";
        }

        if (cozumTablo.iletisim_kontrol == true)
        {
            ws.Cells["D40"].Value = "✔";
        }

        if (cozumTablo.iletisim_teyit == true)
        {
            ws.Cells["E40"].Value = "✔";
        }

        ws.Cells["B42"].Value = cozumTablo.iletisim_detay;

        if (cozumTablo.adimlar_program == true)
        {
            ws.Cells["A51"].Value = "✔";
        }

        if (cozumTablo.adimlar_veritabani == true)
        {
            ws.Cells["C51"].Value = "✔";
        }

        if (cozumTablo.adimlar_server == true)
        {
            ws.Cells["E51"].Value = "✔";
        }

        if (cozumTablo.adimlar_hatailetim == true)
        {
            ws.Cells["G51"].Value = "✔";
            ws.Cells["F54"].Value = cozumTablo.adimlar_hatailetilen;
        }

        ws.Cells["B56"].Value = cozumTablo.cozum_not;

        pck.SaveAs(new FileInfo(reportName));

        Response.Clear();

        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment:filename=" + reportName);
        Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
        Response.End();
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Where is the code concerning epplus and excel generation ?
Please try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
And you should probably not share connection string details when posting code.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I must have missed it. Edited

Comment: If the *antivirus* complains that it can't *open* the file, it's probably a problem of the antivirus, not Excel or EPPlus. What's the *exact* error message? Which Excel version? Is the antivirus up to date?  [This support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/835404/an-out-of-date-antivirus-program-may-cause-errors-when-you-try-to-open) for example explains that you can get a similar message if the antiviurs is out of date. You can copy the contents of any message box with `Ctrl+C`.

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you create a *minimal* sheet, or one with only one or two cells field with normal text? What happens if you *don't* use ✔ ? What if you use the same code in a console application to write to a local file? These tests will help you isolate the issue

Comment: Since you open an existing file to use as a template, are you *sure* that file is OK? Can you open the original?

Comment: First, Excel is asking; "do you want to save it?" When i click Yes, the error is this; "your virus scanner can not open the file because it detected a problem with the file". Im using Excel 2013, and only using Windows Deffender.

Comment: Summarize : In my Index, im click a button, controller is being triggered. Create a new Excel Sheet with EPPlus. The datas are coming from my Database. Database to program, program to Excel...